# sending mail to a configured smtp server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following configuration lines written in `mailer.rb` file to send mails using a particular sever.

```
config.active_record.default_timezone = :local

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "abcprojsmtp",
    :port => 25,
    :authentication => :login
}

config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

Mails are not reaching the destination.

Are there any other configurations missing? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I like to put the ActionMailer settings in environment.rb or in the respective environment/ files. You have more control over how mail is being sent while developing the app.

My guess is you will also need the :user_name and :password options...

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved... it required additonal Domain name to be specified.

It worked :)